# getting numbers from lines of text

Tags: ruby

I want to parse a text file, where
I get numbers that are between parenthesis like
this:

```
1 2 3 (4 - 7) 8 9
1 3 8 (7 - 8) 2 1
1 2 (8 - 10) 3 2

should return an array for each:

array1:
4
7
8

array2:
7
8
10
```

I am thinking of using split for each line, like line.split("("), but that doesn't quite doing the trick.. I was wondering if there is something more sophisticated for the job.

Any help appreciated,

Ted

Comment: Can you clarify why array1 and array2 have those specific values? Why is array1 not [4,7,8,10] or just [4,7]?

Comment: Can you please supply the full code you used, rather than just saying `line.split("(")`?

Comment: @Pam: This is something the OP should specify, but 4, 7, 8 are the first numbers in each of the brackets, and 7, 8, 10 are the second numbers in each of the brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = <<EOS
1 2 3 (4 - 7) 8 9
1 3 8 (7 - 8) 2 1
1 2 (8 - 10) 3 2
EOS
lines = data.split("\n")

def get_inner(lines)
  lines.map { |line| line.partition("(")[2].partition(")")[0].split(" - ")}
end

a1, a2 = *[get_inner(lines).map {|a| a.first },get_inner(lines).map {|a| a.last }]
puts a1
puts a2

# => 
4
7
8
7
8
10
```

Comment: I'd use `puts a1.inspect` or `p a1` rather than `puts a1` (even though that's what the OP used).

Comment: Hey, I was just following the specs! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using things like Substring / IndexOf  as well as split.

You could also try a regular expression to find numbers seperated by spaces in between the ( ) but regular expressions can be a bit of a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm just found this

http://www.rubular.com/ I got the expression I needed
((\d+)-(\d+))